# Defining Transient Pojo (Object) Fields in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity for hibernate orm like below. In this entity, i dont want to persist EntHesaplasma object. so i used @transient annotation.

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CARI_HAREKETLERI")
public class EntCariHareketler {

    private Integer cha_RECno;
    @Resolvable()
    private EntHesaplasma enthesaplasma;        

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "cha_recno", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCha_RECno() {
        return cha_RECno;
    }


    @Transient
    public EntHesaplasma getEnthesaplasma() {
        return enthesaplasma;
    }


    public void setEnthesaplasma(EntHesaplasma enthesaplasma) {
        this.enthesaplasma = enthesaplasma;
    }
```

despite the fact that i added @transient annotation, it gave an error like that

```
Could not determine type for: com.entity.EntHesaplasma, at table:
 CARI_HAREKETLERI, for columns: org.hibernate.mapping.Column(enthesaplasma)]
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply annotations to methods or fields randomly. Normally, you should apply your annotations the same way as @Id..

In EntCariHareketler class Transientshould be like

```
@Transient
private EntHesaplasma enthesaplasma;
```

Comment: @Resolvable annotation is used for another thing, not hibernate.

Comment: OK that's something new to me.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to define it at the field, not getter/setter

```
@Transient
private EntHesaplasma enthesaplasma;
```

Comment: this is worked, thanks, i added it to both getter method and field , but it should taken account on adding right package (import javax.persistence.Transient) , when i added bean.transient , it had given an error.